# Array of JLabel in swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I have recently started using swing in java and I want to add to my JFrame two-dimensional array of JLabels, problem is, that I want to put on the same JFrame antoher things like JButtons etc. And my problem is, that I don't know how to add this array of JLabels.

Comment: I was looking for some specific Layouts, but without succes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a look at the [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).

With this layout you could create a two dimensional layout, in which you could add the `JLabels`.

Something like:

```
JPanel container = new JPanel();
GridLayout experimentLayout = new GridLayout(0,2);

container.setLayout(experimentLayout);

container.add(new JButton("Label 1,1"));
container.add(new JButton("Label 1,2"));
container.add(new JButton("Label 2,1"));
container.add(new JButton("Label 2,2"));
```

This would return a grid like:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| Label 1,1 | Label 1,2 |
+-----------+-----------+
| Label 2,1 | Label 2,2 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: but my problem is specific, because it's arrray of balls in game. And distance between every 2 labels(balls) must be constant. Is GridLayout will work in this way?

Comment: yes, from the `GridLayout` link provided: _Creates a grid layout with the specified number of rows and columns. All components in the layout are given equal size. One, but not both, of rows and cols can be zero, which means that any number of objects can be placed in a row or in a column._